# Is the US government strict on the relative height of the face in a diversity visa lottery application photo?

Tags: usa

From the [DV Instructions](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Diversity-Visa/DV-Instructions-Translations/DV-2018-Instructions-Translations/DV-2018%20Instructions%20English.pdf):

> The head height or facial region size (measured from the top of the head, including the hair, to the bottom of the chin) must be between 50 percent and 69 percent of the image's total height.  The eye height (measured from the bottom of the image to the level of the eyes) should be between 56 percent and 69 percent of the image’s height.

What if it is a bit out of the given range? My colleague made his photo yesterday and the face covers 71% of the image's height. Is his photo still accepted?

Comment: Your colleague might get lucky on measurement error, but given the precision of the requirement I suspect that if they measure the face at 70% or more they will reject the photo.  But questions about the DV lottery are off topic here; they belong on [Expatriates.SE].